# Override rowcommand in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I would like to refresh the page when delete button is clicked in gridview, however I could not find a way to do it, if I write my onrowcommand function

```
if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
{
Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx");
}
```

it does redirect first, and do not delete the record, however I want to be able to delete the record and refresh the page using redirect method afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the delete command, but rather the `RowDeleted` server side event. It fires after the row is deleted and it serves your purpose.

[Link to docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleted.aspx)